# Moongose schema type not working in aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

I have the schema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
      type: String,
      require: true
    },
    paused: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['private', 'group']
    },
})

const PasswordSchema = new Schema({
    password: {
      type: String,
      require: true
    },
    used: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    usedBy: UserSchema
})
```

Like this, works fine

```
await Password.findOne({"usedBy._id": 123}) // 123 is converted to string
```

But aggregate is not converting the **_id**

```
await Password.aggregate().match({ "usedBy._id": 123 }) // 123 keeps number, so the query returns null
```

This is normal? I didn't want to have to convert the _id manually in all queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the issue: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10032

This is expected:

> Mongoose doesn't cast aggregation pipelines. That's because
> aggregation pipelines can, and usually do, change the shape of the
> data in MongoDB. If you need casting, you can use find(), or you can
> use the Query#cast() method to cast the filter:
>
> await Password.aggregate().match(new Query({ "usedBy._id": 123
> }).cast(Password).getFilter())